# HTTP Error 503 when trying to browse public facing website

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We are facing one issue since yesterday.

Our public facing website is developed on SharePoint 2013

When end user tries to open the website they are getting

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
>    error

And after 2,3 minutes it's automatically working fine, and then again after some time getting same issues.

May I please know what would be the issues?

No errors in Log files, Application pool is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`503 error` is due to AppPool is stopped on the servers. But you are saying that site working fine after 2 to 3 minutes.

- If you have more than 1 WFE then might be one wfe is bad
- if site came back online then it means that app pool recycled.
- Check the Setting of App Pool recycling, if it is set recycle after reach to limit then it will recycle automatically
- Also monitor the traffic on the servers
- Check the Event log for more clue why app pool recyled.

Comment: yes one of our front end server is not working.